# Adaptive widgets python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

The problem is that in my program there are widgets of different sizes on different devices, I know that the problem is in absolute sizes, but how can I write the adaptability of widgets?

Comment: You can use [size_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint).

Comment: okay, thank you sir